how to inherit a PresentationController's animationController?
i am attempting to create a matchGeometry-like transition but from a view to a .sheet in swift.
here is a good example of this:
https://x.com/mlaithv/status/1835041850236838265?s=61
the iOS widget picker also has the same transition and its really cool!
natively this isn't possible, but with UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, you can create a custom transition to a new view controller by modifying the animationController function of the delegate.
if i use UISheetPresentationController as the base presentation style for the target view (the sheet in this instance), and i initialize it with the aforementioned custom transition delegate, i am able to pull off the match geometry effect i'm looking for with a snapshot technique mentioned all over here on stack overflow, however i lose the native gestures, interactivity, and feel of a native .sheet
is there a way i can sort of inherit the animationController and by proxy the gestures, interactions, etc of the native UISheet, and then sort of extend/modify it with the matched geometry effect?
